# Refactoring functions with nearly entirely duplicate code but different calls to other methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, methods, refactoring, code-duplication

I'm learning Java and I'm in the middle of online courses and such, and I'm on one of the coding exercises and realized there is a whole lot of duplication between my two methods, found below:

```
private static void addCustomerTransaction() {
    System.out.println("Enter the branch name:");
    String branchName = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the customer name:");
    String customerName = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the transaction");
    while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        scanner.next();
    }
    double transaction = scanner.nextDouble();

    bank.addCustomerTransaction(branchName,customerName,transaction);

}

private static void addCustomer() {
    System.out.println("Enter the branch name:");
    String branchName = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the customer name:");
    String customerName = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the transaction");
    while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        scanner.next();
    }
    double transaction = scanner.nextDouble();

    bank.addCustomer(branchName,customerName,transaction);
}
```

Now obviously the only difference between these two functions is the method call to a bank class object - which end up performing different actions.

I'm wondering how I could refactor these methods so that there is reduced duplication. I get as far as:

```
private static void addCustomerTransaction() {
    customerInput();

}

private static void addCustomer() {
    customerInput();
}

private static void customerInput() {
    System.out.println("Enter the branch name:");
    String branchName = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the customer name:");
    String customerName = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the transaction");
    while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        scanner.next();
    }
    double transaction = scanner.nextDouble();

    bank.addCustomerTransaction(branchName,customerName,transaction);
}
```

But I've no idea how to enable the code to change the method call (currently     `bank.addCustomerTransaction(branchName,customerName,transaction);`
 in the `customerInput` function according to which function is calling the `customerInput`.

Could anyone advise on the next step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one option.

Create an interface for the last method:

```
@FunctionalInterface public interface CustomerOperation {
  void apply(Bank bank, String branch, String customer, String transaction);
}
```

Then your common method can look like this:

```
private static void customerInput(CustomerOperation operation) {
  //common code here
  operation.apply(bank, branchName, customerName, transaction);
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
private static void addCustomerTransaction() {
  customerInput((bank, branchName, customerName, transaction) ->
      bank.addCustomerTransaction(branchName, customerName, transaction));
}

private static void addCustomer() {
  customerInput((bank, branchName, customerName, transaction) ->
      bank.addCustomer(branchName, customerName, transaction));
}
```

Or using method references:

```
private static void addCustomerTransaction() {
  customerInput(Bank::addCustomerTransaction);
}

private static void addCustomer() {
  customerInput(Bank::addCustomer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. That option using method references looks really cool and intuitive... is there any drawback to that? Which is the preferred method, by best practice?

Comment: No there's no drawback. It's mostly a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating a class containing the user input?

```
public class TransactionInfo {

  private String branchName;
  private String customerName;
  private Double transaction;

  public TransactionInfo(String branchName, String customerName, Double transaction) {
    this.branchName = branchName;
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.transaction = transaction;
  }

  ...
}

private static TransactionInfo customerInput() {
  System.out.println("Enter the branch name:");
  String branchName = scanner.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter the customer name:");
  String customerName = scanner.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Enter the transaction");
  while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    scanner.next();
  }
  double transaction = scanner.nextDouble();

  return new TransactionInfo(branchName, customerName, transaction);
}

private static void addCustomerTransaction() {
  TransactionInfo transactionInfo = customerInput();
  bank.addCustomerTransaction(transactionInfo.getBranchName(), transactionInfo.getCustomerName(), transactionInfo.getTransaction());
}

private static void addCustomer() {
  TransactionInfo transactionInfo = customerInput();
  bank.addCustomer(transactionInfo.getBranchName(), transactionInfo.getCustomerName(), transactionInfo.getTransaction());
}
```

If you have control over the class of `bank`, you could think about making the `addCustomer` and `addCustomerTransaction` methods accept `TransactionInfo` as a parameter.

Also, there is probably a better name than `TransactionInfo` for that class. But I hope you get the idea.

You had the right idea extracting the common code into a method. You can see that my solution basically only adds a class for the customer input to use as a return value of the `customerInput` method compared to your approach. Good luck :)

Comment: I really like this solution, it's a toss-up between yours and assylias' answers! I picked his because there is just a bit less new code introduced.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static double readTransaction() {
    System.out.println("Enter the transaction");
    while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
        scanner.next();
    }
    double transaction = scanner.nextDouble();
    return transaction;
}

private static String readCustomerName() {
    System.out.println("Enter the customer name:");
    String customerName = scanner.nextLine();
    return customerName;
}

private static String readBranch() {
    System.out.println("Enter the branch name:");
    String branchName = scanner.nextLine();
    return branchName;
}

private static void addCustomer() {
    String branchName = readBranch();
    String customerName = readCustomerName();
    double transaction = readTransaction();
    bank.addCustomer(branchName,customerName,transaction);
}

private static void addCustomerTransaction() {
    String branchName = readBranch();
    String customerName = readCustomerName();
    double transaction = readTransaction();
    bank.addCustomerTransaction(branchName,customerName,transaction);
}
```

---

Further, you can `Preserve Whole Object` by making a class that contains the branch name, customer name and the transaction, and do the following:

```
class Receipt {
    private String customerName;
    private String branchName;
    private double transaction;

    //Getters and setters...

    public void populateReceipt () {
        customerName = readCustomer();
        branchName = readBranch();
        transaction = readTransaction();
    }
}
```

followed by...

```
private void addCustomer (Receipt receipt) {
    //Modify the method to take in a receipt, rather than its 3 components
    bank.addCustomer(receipt);
}

private void addCustomerTransaction (Receipt receipt) {
    //Modify the method to take in a receipt, rather than its 3 components
    bank.addCustomerTransaction(receipt);
}
```

Comment: While this eliminates the duplicated code, it introduces a hell of a lot more code in its place. What are the advantages to this solution?

Comment: @jpanton: The advantage is that it puts the complexity in the right place and makes the code intuitive. Also it doesn’t add any more code than what already was. There are two solutions in my answer, not one.

Answer (score 0):

you can make them one function with another argument defining if you want to make it as addCustomerTransaction or addCustomer , like this:

```
private static void addCustomer(boolean transaction) {
System.out.println("Enter the branch name:");
String branchName = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter the customer name:");
String customerName = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter the transaction");
while (!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    scanner.next();
}
double transaction = scanner.nextDouble();

if( transaction ) {
       bank.addCustomerTransaction(branchName,customerName,transaction);
  } else {
      bank.addCustomer(branchName,customerName,transaction);
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same idea, but it doesn't seem like good practice - the functions are too different in their goal to be labeled under the same `addCustomer` label - and the boolean of weather to add a transaction or not is a bit too abstract. `bank.addCustomer` is adding a brand new customer and their first transaction, whereas `bank.addCustomerTransaction` is adding a transaction to an existing customer.

Comment: can you provide the whole code plz, i want to make sure what classes are you using, means you can make a class for the customer model and implement the function addTransaction in it.